Spring Framework application only returns 404 errors
Have a very simple class:
@RestController
public class LoggingController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

When I go to the browser it gives me a 404 error. I added a logger which confirms the requests are getting sent. Not sure why the appropriate handler isn't being called.
Incoming request to /test with method GET

Any ideas?

add @RequestMapping("")

Same results as @RequestMapping("/"), which is 404 response.

Is there any @RequestMapping in another controller?, Can you provide what you try to send, ex a captured of Postman, or web browser?

Can you provide a [mre]? Can you reproduce this with a fresh project?

Just a hunch, please check the context path configuration once in application properties for profile being run and whether the same is being sent. Also, is your main application and this controller is in same base package? Just to ensure component scan is working properly or else you need to explicitly define the same

Pls share:

Which dependencies do you have in your pom.xml or build.gradle?
What it your project structure?
Is it Spring boot project or regular Spring project?


This answer fixed my problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53963081/531928

There are two possible reasons here for the controller to return 404.
Scuffed structure
Maybe your Controller resides in a package "above" the main class.
e.g.
src/main/java
|-- controllers
    |-- LoggingControler
|-- framework
    |-- MainApplication

Why doesn't it work? As per default Spring scans all packages (transitively downwards) starting from the one where the MainApplication resides in.
Either move the MainApplication to the most outer common package or declare an (additional) @ComponentScan on the MainApplication class which adds the other packages, where othere classes are gathered in the scan.
src/main/java
|-- controllers
    |-- LoggingControler
|-- MainApplication

Context Path
You might have declared a server.servlet.context-path property in your application.properties.
e.g.
server.servlet.context-path=foo

then the path you should query would be: http://localhost:8080/foo/test

Try adding @RequestMapping annotations to the LoggingController class

Tried to add @RequestMapping("/") with the same result.

Take the [tour]. In my opinion your answer is more suitable as a comment. In any case, it is identical to this comment which the OP already indicated did not solve his problem. You need to earn the comment privilege.

LoggingController may be in other package, is not in the same package with @SpringBootApplication XXXXApplication? add @ComponentScan to scan the loggingcontroller package

You should add @RequestMapping("/insertSomething") to your controller. Then use the full path to access it : yourAdress/insertSomething/test
You should also make sur when you send the request to not add a / at the end of the url (for example if you use some frontend app to make the request).
